# Get values from array returned from model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array that is returned from a model that does not correspond to the view/controller. (i.e Data is from Foo, while I'm in '/bar/'). Therefore I cannot access them via the conventional

```
params[:someItem]
```

So I am trying to extract values like this

```
someVariable = @array[0]
```

However I get a scrambled mess:

```
#<Promotion:0x3b74140>
```

Seeing as that the value I want is an int, I tried calling .to_i, which threw a No Such Method error. Calling to_int gave the same result.

Question: How do I get this value out of the array? And as an aside, why do .to_i and .to_int not work??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my understanding, You are trying to access Array of model objects.
When you write

```
someVariable = @array[0]
```

then it will give you the first model object from @array.
If you want to access object values then you can use like this

```
modelObj = @array[0]
someVariable = modelObj.my_attribue_name
```

Comment: Ahh! Its an array of OBJECTS! Thanks, I thought it was an int array. That solves it.